# How to deobfuscate code in ios objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, deobfuscation

I obfuscated my code using pp-ios-rename or ios-class-guard by following the steps in below link

https://github.com/preemptive/PPiOS-Rename

But when I try to deobfuscate my code, I couldnt do it and there is no support for that anywhere. Please help me in deobfuscating the code. Even my storyboard scenes got obfuscated, may be I have done something wrong in the process.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The repo suggests reverting to a previous commit as it looks like there's no automated way to undo it. You can reference the `symbols.map` file to see the mappings.

If you still have this file you could try inverting the obfuscated names with the original names then running this command:

```
ppios-rename --obfuscate-sources --symbols-map symbols.map
```

However, this kind of source obfuscation is not normally recommended due to these kind of significant trade-offs, unless running it as part of an automated CI/CD pipeline.